# Review queue reporting false first answers?

Tags: support

I was going through the "first post" review queue, and I came across this answer. I thought "93 rep? No answers? Seems fishy". I looked at his profile, and he [has answers dating back to Oct 15th.](https://askubuntu.com/users/169318/duck?tab=answers&sort=newest) What's up with that?

As a side note, it looks like the answer has been deleted now, [as the question in... question currently has no answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537517/disable-fade-in-fade-out-visual-effect-of-unity-greeter/537539#537539)

Additionally, at the time of writing his profile says last seen 22 hours ago, but that answer was 5 hours ago.

[image]

Comment: I bet it was a test.

Comment: While this does not seem to be the case here, remember that any user with >200 rep on any of the Stack Exchange sites will automatically get an [association bonus](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) of 100 rep on any new account they create so ~100 rep can still be a new user.

Comment: @terdon Yeah, 93 just seemed to be a weird number to me, so I looked into it.

Comment: @Mateo you might be right, I forgot about the random tests interspersed. I guess I was paying attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a test. The answer *was* a real answer, once upon a time, it has, however, since been deleted. As I did not perform the deletion I am not 100% sure as to the reason it was deleted, but I suspect it was because the post isn't an answer just a vague "poke around here..".

The review system has used the post as an audit several times already.